# How to check if a word is in each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column designated to town names. After each town name I am adding the word "NSW" (e.g. "Sydney" will become "Sydney NSW"). However, this means even when a town already has NSW written, the script will add it again (e.g. "Narara NSW" will become "Narara NSW NSW"). How can I check if the name already has NSW and only add the string if NSW is not present. Here is my code so far:

```
#Adds "NSW" to the end of each town in the dataframe and then adds these changes to to the csv
df['FullAddress'] = df['FullAddress'] + ' NSW'
print(df)
df.to_csv('latLongTest.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal preference is to usually use `np.where()` in a situation like this:

```
df['FullAddress'] = np.where((df['FullAddress'].str.endswith(' NSW')), df['FullAddress'], df['FullAddress'] + ' NSW')
```

It is vectorized and similar to an excel if statement `IF(CONDITION, THEN, ELSE)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas.Series.where` with `pandas.Series.str.endswith`:

```
s = pd.Series(["Sydney", "Narara NSW"])
s.where(s.str.endswith("NSW"), lambda x: x + " NSW")
```

Output:

```
0    Sydney NSW
1    Narara NSW
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'FullAddress': ['Sydney', 'Sydney NSW', 'Narara NSW', 'Narara']})
df['FullAddress'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.FullAddress if x.FullAddress.endswith(' NSW') else x.FullAddress + ' NSW', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  FullAddress
0  Sydney NSW
1  Sydney NSW
2  Narara NSW
3  Narara NSW
```